# Eclipse: How to move between TABS in a circular way

Tags: eclipse, tabs

I'm using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> OR <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd> to move between *TABS*.

But the problem with this is that when you reach the last *TAB* you need to move through all of the *TABS* in order to reach the first one again.

I know I can use  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> OR <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> but this is not fast as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd>.

Is there a way to make <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> / <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd> works in a circular way? (Like moving between *TABS* in chrome for example)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this feature is not supported on **Eclipse Indigo**. I downloaded **Indigo** and it works there by default.

Answer (score 2):

I use Juno SR1 which does circular with Ctrl + Page Down.

Which version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+page up/down work fine for me. Try to update you eclipse :)

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/about, to get more understanding about questions/answers here on SO. Your contribution is not answering the question. It is more a comment, which you can add once you'll increase your reputation: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation